# How do I declare the body of a POST with the fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am building a comments section onto a Node/Express app for family reunions.  I first wrote it all on the server side, but then ran into the issue where I was unable to update the DOM after posting the comment without refreshing the page.

My research yielded that I could use AJAX or the fetch API to do this, client-side.

I'm using some client-side JavaScript to post comments.  I have a route for the POST request:

```js
router.post('/:reunionId', isAuth, reunionController.postComment);
```

The controller code is:

```js
exports.postComment = (req, res, next) => {
  const commentText = req.body.newComment;
  const reunionId = req.body.reunionId;

  const foundReunion = Reunion.findById(reunionId)
    .populate({
      path: 'comments',
      options: { sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
    })
    .then((reunion) => {
      console.log(reunion);

      const comment = new Comment({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        text: commentText,
        reunionId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(reunionId),
        userId: req.user._id,
      });

      foundReunion.comments.push(comment);
      comment.save();
      foundReunion.save();
      console.log('Operation completed successfully');
      return foundReunion;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const newError = new Error(error);
      newError.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(newError);
    });
};
```

And the client-side code:

```js
const commentForm = document.getElementById('comment-form');
const commentInput = document.getElementById('newComment');
const commentsContainer = document.getElementById('allComments');
let commentText = document.getElementById('newComment').value;
const reunionId = document.getElementById('reunionId').value;
const csrfToken = document.getElementById('csrf').value;

commentForm.addEventListener('submit', handleCommentSubmit, false);
commentInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  commentText = event.target.value;
});
async function handleCommentSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Someone clicked the comment submit button...');
  console.log(csrfToken); // This works.
  console.log(reunionId); // This works.
  console.log(commentText); // This works.

  const url = `http://localhost:3006/reunions/${reunionId}`;

  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
      },
      body: { // This is not working.
        reunionId,
        commentText,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const d = response.comment.createdAt.getDate();
      const m = monthNames[response.comment.createdAt.getMonth()];
      const y = response.comment.createdAt.getFullYear();

      const commentDiv = document.createElement('div');
      commentDiv.classList.add('comments-container');
      const commentP = doucment.createElement('p');
      commentP.classList.add('comment-header-text');
      const email = response.comment.userId.email;
      const hr = document.createElement('hr');

      commentP.textContent = `On ${m}+ ' ' +${d}+ ', ' +${y}, ${email} wrote:`;
      commentDiv.appendChild(commentP);
      commentDiv.appendChild(commentText);
      commentDiv.appendChild(hr);

      commentsContainer.appendChild(commentDiv);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

The client makes the POST request, properly passes the csrf token, but the server cannot read the reunionId or commentText from the body of the request. I get Reunion.findOne({ null }) in the server logs.

I am simply not sure what Content-Type to declare, whether I need to at all, or how to pass the two pieces of data I need in the body of the call to fetch.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: The body should be a string or `FormData`, not an object. The string should be either JSON or URL-encoded data, depending on what middleware the controller is using.

Answer (score 2):

The body of a post must always be a string. What you are missing is you need to JSON.strigify your object and them make add the content-type header to specify that the body is application/json:

```
fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        reunionId,
        commentText,
      }),
    })
```